# Remove "Silent Process Exit" folder from temp directory

Tags: windows-10, debug

How to disable processes the monitoring of silent process exits and get rid of the `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Silent Process Exit` folder?

I looked it up and found that it has something to do with gflags or silent process exit monitoring in windows debugger, it is saving dumps of `cmd.exe` every time I exit the program regularly, when I use `taskkill /im cmd.exe` it doesn't save a dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You or some installed program have somehow enabled the CMD process
for the tracing of silent exits (non-crash).
This is usually done by driver programs, but I don't know of
a driver that traces CMD...

See the article
[Monitoring Silent Process Exit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/registry-entries-for-silent-process-exit).
It lists the following registry keys where this could be set:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\ProcessName\GlobalFlag`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SilentProcessExit`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SilentProcessExit\ProcessName`

`ProcessName` might be CMD in the above.

Check the above registry keys. In my computer these keys do not
exist, so can probably be deleted from yours.
Reboot afterwards.
I suggest creating at least a System Restore Point before doing any
registry modifications.

Comment: A 0x200 was stored in my registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\cmd.exe\GlobalFlag`. Thanks for helping me out!